# CiviCRM does not have permission to write temp files - halts the system

Tags: wordpress, permissions

My website stopped working due to a CiviCRM problem, all I see is:
"CiviCRM does not have permission to write temp files in ...wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/,exiting"

My hosting service may have recently updated to php 7.4.
Seeing old solutions to this problem, I deleted all the folders in wp/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/
but left .htaccess unchanged.
That did not solve the problem.
Should I delete everything in .../uploads/civicrm/templates_c/
Has anybody had this problem and fixed it?

Comment: You can delete everything under `.../uploads/civicrm/templates_c/ `  Check the permissions look correct to allow the user running the webserver to create files, but you might need to check with your hosting service.

Comment: Thanks for your question and I'm glad Aidan's solution worked. Please help us out by posting it in the form of an answer and accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you. Deleting everything as suggested worked. Problem solved.